# Is there any evidence for the claim that the Catholic church suppressed translation of Scripture?

Tags: catholicism, history, translation

There is a popular Protestant polemic that Catholics don't (or didn't) want people to read the Bible.  It is often furthermore assumed that the Catholic Church went so far as to *ban* people from having the Bible in their own language.

Supporting the claim are the stories of:

- [Martin Luther](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martin_Luther#Diet_of_Worms) who is sometimes thought to have been persecuted for translating the Bible into German, but who in fact was accused of heresy, and in any event, was not the first to translate the Bible into German.
- [William Tyndale](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Tyndale#cite_note-3) who was executed for heresy, but also did not even make the first English translation (rather there were others already extant)
- [John Wycliffe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Wycliffe) who is often credited with the first English Bible, although older versions went back to the 6th Century, and who nonetheless was never charged with heresy until a good 30 years or so after his death.

In each of these cases, however, the position does not seem to be the act of translating the Bible, or of making it available, but rather of heretical teachings from these translations.

And, clearly the example of the Jesuits, translating the Scripture into hundreds of languages, seems to run counter to the claim that translating Scripture or encouraging lay popele to read it was heretical.

So, the question is, is there any papal directive that specifically addresses the possession of the Scripture in a vulgar (i.e. native) tongue, or addresses the translation of Scripture outside of Latin in a negative light?

Comment: I understood from High School English that the origin of the English language is identified to be in the year 1066, so I'm not sure there could be translations prior to that.

Comment: Bible-researacher.com addresses the same question at [section three of this page](http://www.bible-researcher.com/catholic-intro.html).

Comment: @Narnian that would be the advent of middle English, when [french](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norman_conquest_of_England) was introduced to the language and it became less of a Germanic language. Old English is much older then that, but is much more related to German then it is to modern English.

Comment: @AffableGeek: I can't help but think it has something to do with this question I asked, not particularly the argumentation (translations) but the power and control: http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/15903/which-denomination-recognizes-that-parts-of-the-bible-have-been-modified-in-the

Comment: @GregMcNulty So, I looked at that question, and I disagree. Your question is along the lines of "How do I know someone didn't add doctrine?"  Mine really is "Does the Catholic Church force people to hear the Scripture read by Priests in Latin?" kind of thing.  I'm talking about translation, you are talking about modification.  Very different beasts.

Comment: @AffableGeek: This book may be of interest to you..if you haven't already read it.  I think chapter XI "Abundance of vernacular Bibles before Wycliffe" is relevant to this question.


 http://jloughnan.tripod.com/howbible.htm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quoting from *The Story of Christianity,* chapter thirty (emphasis added):<sup>1</sup>

> When Alexander died, Hildebrand was elected pope, although the order prescribed by the Second Lateran Council was reversed, for it was the people who demanded his election, and the cardinals who agreed. He took the name of Gregory VII, and continued the work of reformation in which he had been engaged for years. His dream was of a world united under the papacy, as one flock under one shepherd. **Among the many steps he took in this direction, he declared that the Bible should not be translated into vernacular languages, for the ministry of teaching and interpretation must be in the hands of Rome...**

**Additional Context:** Chapter thirty is entitled "Movements of Renewal," and Gonzalez is describing the Roman Catholic Church in the eleventh century, following the corruption which existed during and after the decline of the Carolingian empire. The "reformation" referred to is not the Protestant Reformation of the sixteenth century, but rather the eleventh century ecclesiastical reformation internal to the RCC, as initiated by monks from Cluny and other monasteries.

---

1. *The Story of Christianity, Revised Edition,* by Justo Gonzalez. Volume I, p. 337.

Comment: Wikipedia uses Deanesly, Margaret (1920) The Lollard Bible and Other Medieval Biblical Versions. Cambridge: University Press as a source for both Gregory VII and Innocent III. If Deansley or Gonzalez (2010?) quote sources we might have more than a bare claim. Wikipedia suggests early translators were attacked for heresy, not specifically for translating, and that many scholars disagree with Deansley.

Answer (score 3):

The evidence that the Church has ever completely forbidden the translation of scripture is [dubious at best](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bible_translations_in_the_Middle_Ages). As is stated in Wikipedia, there are a few times when a given college of bishops or a given region might have forbidden the vernacular, but these were almost always at times when mis-translations were more common than adequate ones. In these cases, the Church decided to [whitelist instead of blacklist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453285/what-is-whitelist-and-blacklist-data).

Comment: I think you should be looking at the documents of The Church for this - not Wikipedia.

Comment: Tyndale was hanged by the Church for his translation of the Bible, as were several others.

Comment: @Waeshael Tyndale was killed by agents of the King of England because he opposed the divorce.

Comment: @Waeshael Since you are the one insisting that there is a document that shows the Catholic Church collectively forbid the translation of Bibles, it is incumbent upon you to provide a demonstration that one exists. It is not my responsibility to prove that none have ever existed.

Comment: I have moved the answers to a conversation stack. Hope you will have a look at it.

Answer (score 2):

Not today. The Vatican uses the Vulgate in the Liturgy, and does not prohibit the Liturgy used outside the Vatican to be translated into the vernacular of any country. Since Vatican II, scholars and clergy have been encouraged to read other translations. In the USA, the American Catholic Church has adopted several translations including RSV, NAB, NSAB, and NRSV.

In the [fourth session](http://history.hanover.edu/texts/trent/ct04.html) of the Council of Trent (1545-1563) the Vulgate was declared to be authoritative. It had already been in use by the Roman Catholic Church since the 5th. cent.

> Moreover, the same sacred and holy Synod,--considering that no small utility may accrue to the Church of God, if it be made known which out of all the Latin editions, now in circulation, of the sacred books, is to be held as authentic,--ordains and declares, that the said old and vulgate edition, which, by the lengthened usage of so many years, has been approved of in the Church, be, in public lectures, disputations, sermons and expositions, held as authentic; and that no one is to dare, or presume to reject it under any pretext whatever.

Translation into other languages **by Roman Catholics** was forbidden by Papal decree until Vatican II.
Of course, before the Reformation everyone in the West was a Roman Catholic, including Tyndale.

The Eastern Orthodox churches are different. Their New Testament and Old Testament have always been in Greek, and Syrian since the 4th. cent. (The Aramaic Gospels in the Brit. Museum are signed and dated AD 464.)

Comment: Could you reference that decree?  I've already done a +1, but before I accept, I'd love to have that.  Thanks!

Comment: OK, first, even if the Council had said that (which it didn't, by the by), that was a legal norm, and as such that standard would have been abrogated by the Pio-Benedictine Canon Law.

Comment: As a proof that translation was acceptable and common, I submit the original, French Jerusalem Bible. That was completed in 1956 and was properly endorsed by a Church official.

Comment: @IgnatiusTheophorus you seem extreamly biased towards the church not banning. Also the question deals with medieval times, which 1956 does not qualify as. You can not use that then as 'proof' that 1000 years ago translations were appropriate, common, and acceptable...

Comment: Start with the COuncil of Trent "scripture tradition and the Canon" 8 April 1546, second Decree. Then Gregory XVI 8 May 1844 on "Sectarian Bible Societies" Section 84 which includes the statement "readings of the vernacular translation were permitted if they were "approved by the Holy See" and published with "notes taken from the Holy Fathers of the Church..." - In America, bible translations are generally approved only by the American Catholic Church.

Comment: Leo XIII 25 January 1897: Use of Non-Catholic editions of sacred scripture.  "All translations of the Holy Bible done by non-catholics of any denomination are forbidden, particularly those coming from Bible Societies." ref: "The Church and the Bible - official documents of the Catholic Church." p 84

Comment: @Waeshael The question actually has to do with the Catholic  Church through all of history, and your statement specifically had to do with the Church between Trent and Vatican II. I cited one example which was between those two events which directly and immediately refutes your position.

Comment: If you are correct in your interpretation, then the Douay Rheims Bible, published within 60 years of the end of Trent, would be excommunicable, but instead it held and imprimatur!

Comment: All of your citations prove that Catholics were not supposed to be using editions which were not Church approved. That has nothing to do with the question at hand: whether Catholics were allowed to have translations at all. The fact of the matter is that they were not only allowed to have them, they were encouraged to read them!

Comment: Ignatius: The question was "is there any Papal directive ... [regarding] the translation of literature outside the Latin in a negative way?" Obviously there has been - Leo XIII 25 January 1897.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9697/discussion-between-waeshael-and-ignatius-theophorus)

Comment: This answer would be much better if it reconciled the existence of many vernacular editions of Scripture produced by Catholics before Vatican II (Douay Rheims, Confraternity, Knox, and Jerusalem come immediately to mind) with this confusing sentence: "Translation into other languages by Roman Catholics was forbidden by Papal decree until Vatican II."